# At what power of magnetic resonance does metal embedded in a person start to be pulled?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, plasma-physics, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

What is the level (number) of magnetic resonance necessary to provide an unsafe environment for a person who has metal embedded in their upper body? At what level do the metal shards start to be pulled? Can a person who has metal shards in their upper body be around welding or plasma cutting machines?

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) three things involved here:

First - an object can get magnetized in the presence of a magnetic field. The degree of magnetization will be stronger for ferromagnetic materials; the ability to do so is expressed with the relative permeability, $\mu_r$. The *force* of that object will further depend on the *gradient* of the magnetic field: in a uniform field (the middle of an MRI scanner) there is no net force on a stationary metallic object. However, when a patient is moved *into* the scanner, they pass through a region with very high magnetic gradient (going from 0.5 Gauss to 300 kGauss over a couple of meters requires there to be a gradient). So that’s the first dangerous thing that happens to a patient with metal inside - regardless of how fast or slow they are moving, and regardless of whether the scanner is otherwise energized (assuming it has a stationary magnetic field). Lucky for us, most medical grade implants are made of low permeability material which reduced this risk. The same may not be true if you have “unknown metal” (example: grenade fragments) inside.

The second issue relates to eddy currents. There is a curious experiment you can do, in which you take an aluminum block and place it on the table of a MRI scanner, at the center of the magnet, at an angle. When you let it go, the block doesn’t simply topple over (!). Instead it will gently “keel over” in slow motion. This is the effect of eddy currents: as the metal moves, a current is induced which in turn generates a force to counter the “changing magnetic field” (as seen by the falling block). A little bit of motion is enough to create quite a force. Translate this to a situation where you have a lump of metal inside your body: when you are moving into the scanner, the eddy currents will “resist” that motion. The faster you move, the greater the force. Lucky for you, the MRI table moves slowly - probably not enough to rip metal out of your body through eddy currents.

About those eddy currents: during actual imaging, very strong (and rapidly varying) gradients are set up in order to manipulate the spin state. The rate of change can be on the order of 100 T/m/s. That generates strong eddy currents in metal, and again this can give rise to significant forces - but these will be of the “twist” rather than “pull” kind.

The same eddy currents can lead to significant heating in sufficiently large pieces of metal; while that doesn’t result in “pull”, a sufficiently large piece of metal could get uncomfortably hot.

Finally, the MRI scanner employs a powerful RF transmitter to excite the protons (or, occasionally, other nuclei). For a 3T magnet, the resonant frequency is 128 MHz, putting the quarter wavelength a bit under a meter in air, considerably shorter in water. This can lead to resonance on an appropriate shaped piece of metal, and result in heating. Actually a patient’s legs are quite a good “antenna” and techs will usually take care to make sure your legs are not touching so as to prevent making a closed loop circuit out of them…

In short - there are plenty of bits of physics that can hurt you when you go into an MRI scanner. This is why there is a safety check, and why they ask you about any potential metal inside your body. Many implants are designed to be quite safe: but you have to trust the experts on this and not “try it and hope for the best”.

MRIs save many lives - but accidents do happen. The forces and energies involved are substantial. Luckily, not all those accidents [end up hurting people](https://images.app.goo.gl/CD7PYC2mKALpaHkf7)

Better follow the safety rules.